# Does unenchanted armor reduce your fall damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wondering if unenchanted armor reduces the amount of fall damage you take. I know that if you wear Feather Falling or Protection your fall damage is reduced. However, does wearing diamond armor with no enchants help prevent fall damage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No:**

Unenchanted armor cannot reduce fall damage.  I tested this out with an experiment:

First I jumped of an 11 block high tower with no armor:

As seen in the picture 4 hearts of damage was taken.
[image]

I then jumper from the same tower with full leather armor:
[image]

The same amount of damage was taken with full leather armor.  I then tested it with a protection 2 enchanted helmet on instead, and the result was:

[image]

Half a heart of damage was reduced only if the armor was enchanted.

I tested this with iron armor also and the results were the same!

Answer (score 0):

**No**, unechanted armour **doesn't reduce fall damage**. *It reduces only*:

- Melee Damage
- Missile Damage
- Blast Damage
- Fire Damage

…but **no Fall Damage**. *So, only enchanted armour reduces your Fall Damage*.